# WPF UserControl Binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties

I've been trying to find a solution to this problem, but I'm quite confused by the possible approaches I've found on the Internet.

I have created a UserControl containing a slider for DateTime.

```
<UserControl x:Name="root">
    <Grid x:Name="gridPanel">
       <Slider x:Name="slider" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="34" Width="479"
                    Minimum="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=Minimum, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=dateToDoubleConverter}}"
                    Maximum="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=Maximum, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=dateToDoubleConverter}}"
                    Value="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=Value, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=dateToDoubleConverter}}" />
        <Label x:Name="lblStartTime" Content="{Binding ElementName=slider, Path=Minimum, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=doubleToStringConverter}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,73,0,0" FontSize="10"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblStopTime" Content="{Binding ElementName=slider, Path=Maximum, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=doubleToStringConverter}}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,73,10,0" FontSize="10"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code behind:

```
      public SliderPanel() {
         InitializeComponent();
         gridPanel.DataContext = this;
      }

      #region Dependency Property - Minimum
      public DateTime Minimum {
         get { return (DateTime)GetValue(MinimumProperty); }
         set { SetValue(MinimumProperty, value); }
      }

      public static readonly DependencyProperty MinimumProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register("Minimum", typeof(DateTime), typeof(SliderPanel), new UIPropertyMetadata(DateTime.Now));
      #endregion

      #region Dependency Property - Maximum
      public DateTime Maximum {
         get { return (DateTime)GetValue(MaximumProperty); }
         set { SetValue(MaximumProperty, value); }
      }

      public static readonly DependencyProperty MaximumProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register("Maximum", typeof(DateTime), typeof(SliderPanel), new UIPropertyMetadata(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)));
      #endregion

      #region Dependency Property - Value
      public DateTime Value {
         get { return (DateTime)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
         set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
      }

      public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(DateTime), typeof(SliderPanel), new UIPropertyMetadata(DateTime.Now, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnValueChanged)));

      public static void OnValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
         SliderPanel sP = (SliderPanel)d;
         if (e.Property == SliderPanel.ValueProperty) {
            sP.slider.Value = ((DateTime)e.NewValue).Ticks;
         }
      }
      #endregion
```

In my main window, I use the UserControl and bind some properties via code, such as:

```
     System.Windows.Data.Binding bndPlayTime = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("CurrentPlayTime");
     bndPlayTime.Source = controller;
     bndPlayTime.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
     lblCurPlayTime.SetBinding(System.Windows.Controls.TextBox.TextProperty, bndPlayString);
     sliderPanel.SetBinding(SliderPanel.ValueProperty, bndPlayTime);
```

The Controller class implements INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
  public DateTime CurrentPlayTime {
     get {
        return currentPlayTime;
     }

     set {
        if (DateTime.Compare(currentPlayTime, value) != 0) {
           currentPlayTime = value;
           NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentPlayTime");
        }
     }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
     if (PropertyChanged != null)
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
```

The CurrentPlayTime property is constantly updated by a timer. Now I would like the slider to move accordingly. The binding to the label works. The label is updated on a regular basis. However, the binding to the dependency property of the UserControl does not cause the slider value to update (even though I have implemented a callback method). Am I missing something?

Please bear with me, I'm very new to WPF. I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you tried UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged for your slider value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to set the [binding mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.mode.aspx) to [TwoWay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingmode.aspx) on your bindings ?

Comment: OMG how stupid. I always changed the mode in the wrong place (in the XAML of the UserControl itself and not in the main window)!!